# What logs to check if snapshot for instance get deleted as soon it gets queued in Openstack

Tags: openstack, snapshot, openstack-nova, openstack-horizon, openstack-glance

I have tried creating a snapshot for the running instance in our openstack setup. Upon clicking, create snapshot creation gets queued but after few minutes it is getting deleted. Not sure what logs to check. 
I have gone through glance-all.log in controller. Observed following messages

glance-all.log :

```
<150>Aug 24 10:20:23 node-1 glance-registry: 2018-08-24 10:20:23.150 9643 INFO glance.registry.api.v1.images [req-3b08e166-c883-4abd-8f14-5169bbe77797 2771a2a4e11d41c9a79262539ff1505e 92d211537de24d0899be89c320a69a53 - - -] Updating metadata for image 3aee82a2-c4a1-4945-9bd1-5b6ccb2ebf77
<150>Aug 24 10:20:23 node-1 glance-registry: 2018-08-24 10:20:23.151 9643 INFO eventlet.wsgi.server [req-3b08e166-c883-4abd-8f14-5169bbe77797 2771a2a4e11d41c9a79262539ff1505e 92d211537de24d0899be89c320a69a53 - - -] 192.168.0.2 - - [24/Aug/2018 10:20:23] "PUT /images/3aee82a2-c4a1-4945-9bd1-5b6ccb2ebf77 HTTP/1.1" 200 885 0.031617
<150>Aug 24 10:20:23 node-1 glance-registry: 2018-08-24 10:20:23.199 9643 INFO glance.registry.api.v1.images [req-3b08e166-c883-4abd-8f14-5169bbe77797 2771a2a4e11d41c9a79262539ff1505e 92d211537de24d0899be89c320a69a53 - - -] Successfully deleted image 3aee82a2-c4a1-4945-9bd1-5b6ccb2ebf77
<150>Aug 24 10:20:23 node-1 glance-registry: 2018-08-24 10:20:23.200 9643 INFO eventlet.wsgi.server [req-3b08e166-c883-4abd-8f14-5169bbe77797 2771a2a4e11d41c9a79262539ff1505e 92d211537de24d0899be89c320a69a53 - - -] 192.168.0.2 - - [24/Aug/2018 10:20:23] "DELETE /images/3aee82a2-c4a1-4945-9bd1-5b6ccb2ebf77 HTTP/1.1" 200 722 0.047676
```

nova-compute.log :

```
2018-08-24 05:57:22.434 53672 INFO nova.compute.manager [req-27904691-aada-4e7b-a5d3-64c5a8990e20 2771a2a4e11d41c9a79262539ff1505e 92d211537de24d0899be89c320a69a53 - - -] [instance: 343bdab5-1002-4e63-a37a-70f953847088] instance snapshotting
2018-08-24 05:57:23.201 53672 INFO nova.compute.resource_tracker [req-75c74bc3-26d1-409e-84cd-f1a5730fc70a - - - - -] Compute_service record updated for node-2.domain.tld:node-2.domain.tld
2018-08-24 05:57:24.133 53672 INFO nova.compute.manager [req-4a1bd5c0-d54f-4429-a8ff-3e9cb46011ec - - - - -] [instance: 343bdab5-1002-4e63-a37a-70f953847088] VM Paused (Lifecycle Event)
2018-08-24 05:57:24.383 53672 INFO nova.compute.manager [req-4a1bd5c0-d54f-4429-a8ff-3e9cb46011ec - - - - -] [instance: 343bdab5-1002-4e63-a37a-70f953847088] During sync_power_state the instance has a pending task (image_snapshot). Skip.
2018-08-24 05:57:52.233 53672 INFO nova.virt.libvirt.driver [req-27904691-aada-4e7b-a5d3-64c5a8990e20 2771a2a4e11d41c9a79262539ff1505e 92d211537de24d0899be89c320a69a53 - - -] [instance: 343bdab5-1002-4e63-a37a-70f953847088] Beginning cold snapshot process
2018-08-24 05:58:07.238 53672 INFO nova.compute.manager [-] [instance: 343bdab5-1002-4e63-a37a-70f953847088] VM Stopped (Lifecycle Event)
2018-08-24 05:58:07.303 53672 INFO nova.compute.manager [req-63b9a442-4483-4238-97c3-0c20ef1dccc2 - - - - -] [instance: 343bdab5-1002-4e63-a37a-70f953847088] During sync_power_state the instance has a pending task (image_pending_upload). Skip.
2018-08-24 05:58:17.561 53672 INFO nova.compute.resource_tracker [req-75c74bc3-26d1-409e-84cd-f1a5730fc70a - - - - -] Auditing locally available compute resources for node node-2.domain.tld
2018-08-24 05:58:20.590 53672 INFO nova.compute.resource_tracker [req-75c74bc3-26d1-409e-84cd-f1a5730fc70a - - - - -] Total usable vcpus: 72, total allocated vcpus: 44
2018-08-24 05:58:20.591 53672 INFO nova.compute.resource_tracker [req-75c74bc3-26d1-409e-84cd-f1a5730fc70a - - - - -] Final resource view: name=node-2.domain.tld phys_ram=257584MB used_ram=135680MB phys_disk=1618GB used_disk=880GB total_vcpus=72 used_vcpus=44 pci_stats=[PciDevicePool(count=53,numa_node=0,product_id='1515',tags={dev_type='type-VF',physical_network='physnet6'},vendor_id='8086'), PciDevicePool(count=53,numa_node=0,product_id='1515',tags={dev_type='type-VF',physical_network='physnet7'},vendor_id='8086'), PciDevicePool(count=59,numa_node=0,product_id='1515',tags={dev_type='type-VF',physical_network='physnet8'},vendor_id='8086')]
2018-08-24 05:58:22.985 53672 INFO nova.compute.resource_tracker [req-75c74bc3-26d1-409e-84cd-f1a5730fc70a - - - - -] Compute_service record updated for node-2.domain.tld:node-2.domain.tld
2018-08-24 05:59:16.119 53672 INFO nova.compute.manager [req-4a1bd5c0-d54f-4429-a8ff-3e9cb46011ec - - - - -] [instance: 343bdab5-1002-4e63-a37a-70f953847088] VM Started (Lifecycle Event)
2018-08-24 05:59:17.427 53672 INFO nova.compute.manager [req-4a1bd5c0-d54f-4429-a8ff-3e9cb46011ec - - - - -] [instance: 343bdab5-1002-4e63-a37a-70f953847088] During sync_power_state the instance has a pending task (image_pending_upload). Skip.
2018-08-24 05:59:17.428 53672 INFO nova.compute.manager [req-4a1bd5c0-d54f-4429-a8ff-3e9cb46011ec - - - - -] [instance: 343bdab5-1002-4e63-a37a-70f953847088] VM Resumed (Lifecycle Event)
2018-08-24 05:59:17.557 53672 INFO nova.compute.resource_tracker [req-75c74bc3-26d1-409e-84cd-f1a5730fc70a - - - - -] Auditing locally available compute resources for node node-2.domain.tld
2018-08-24 05:59:19.828 53672 INFO nova.compute.manager [req-4a1bd5c0-d54f-4429-a8ff-3e9cb46011ec - - - - -] [instance: 343bdab5-1002-4e63-a37a-70f953847088] During sync_power_state the instance has a pending task (image_pending_upload). Skip.
2018-08-24 05:59:23.094 53672 INFO nova.compute.manager [req-27904691-aada-4e7b-a5d3-64c5a8990e20 2771a2a4e11d41c9a79262539ff1505e 92d211537de24d0899be89c320a69a53 - - -] [instance: 343bdab5-1002-4e63-a37a-70f953847088] Successfully reverted task state from image_pending_upload on failure for instance.
2018-08-24 05:59:23.100 53672 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher [req-27904691-aada-4e7b-a5d3-64c5a8990e20 2771a2a4e11d41c9a79262539ff1505e 92d211537de24d0899be89c320a69a53 - - -] Exception during message handling: internal error: unable to execute QEMU command 'device_add': Device initialization failed
2018-08-24 05:59:23.100 53672 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher Traceback (most recent call last):
2018-08-24 05:59:23.100 53672 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oslo_messaging/rpc/dispatcher.py", line 138, in _dispatch_and_reply
2018-08-24 05:59:23.100 53672 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher     incoming.message))
2018-08-24 05:59:23.100 53672 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oslo_messaging/rpc/dispatcher.py", line 185, in _dispatch
2018-08-24 05:59:23.100 53672 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher     return self._do_dispatch(endpoint, method, ctxt, args)
2018-08-24 05:59:23.100 53672 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oslo_messaging/rpc/dispatcher.py", line 127, in _do_dispatch
2018-08-24 05:59:23.100 53672 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher     result = func(ctxt, **new_args)
2018-08-24 05:59:23.100 53672 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/exception.py", line 110, in wrapped
2018-08-24 05:59:23.100 53672 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher     payload)
2018-08-24 05:59:23.100 53672 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oslo_utils/excutils.py", line 220, in __exit__
2018-08-24 05:59:23.100 53672 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher     self.force_reraise()
2018-08-24 05:59:23.100 53672 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oslo_utils/excutils.py", line 196, in force_reraise
2018-08-24 05:59:23.100 53672 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher     six.reraise(self.type_, self.value, self.tb)
2018-08-24 05:59:23.100 53672 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/exception.py", line 89, in wrapped
2018-08-24 05:59:23.100 53672 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher     return f(self, context, *args, **kw)
2018-08-24 05:59:23.100 53672 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/compute/manager.py", line 359, in decorated_function
2018-08-24 05:59:23.100 53672 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher     LOG.warning(msg, e, instance=instance)
2018-08-24 05:59:23.100 53672 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oslo_utils/excutils.py", line 220, in __exit__
2018-08-24 05:59:23.100 53672 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher     self.force_reraise()
2018-08-24 05:59:23.100 53672 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oslo_utils/excutils.py", line 196, in force_reraise
2018-08-24 05:59:23.100 53672 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher     six.reraise(self.type_, self.value, self.tb)
2018-08-24 05:59:23.100 53672 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/compute/manager.py", line 328, in decorated_function
2018-08-24 05:59:23.100 53672 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher     return function(self, context, *args, **kwargs)
2018-08-24 05:59:23.100 53672 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/compute/manager.py", line 387, in decorated_function
2018-08-24 05:59:23.100 53672 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher     kwargs['instance'], e, sys.exc_info())
2018-08-24 05:59:23.100 53672 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oslo_utils/excutils.py", line 220, in __exit__
2018-08-24 05:59:23.100 53672 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher     self.force_reraise()
2018-08-24 05:59:23.100 53672 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oslo_utils/excutils.py", line 196, in force_reraise
2018-08-24 05:59:23.100 53672 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher     six.reraise(self.type_, self.value, self.tb)
2018-08-24 05:59:23.100 53672 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher     six.reraise(self.type_, self.value, self.tb)
2018-08-24 05:59:23.100 53672 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/compute/manager.py", line 328, in decorated_function
2018-08-24 05:59:23.100 53672 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher     return function(self, context, *args, **kwargs)
2018-08-24 05:59:23.100 53672 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/compute/manager.py", line 387, in decorated_function
2018-08-24 05:59:23.100 53672 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher     kwargs['instance'], e, sys.exc_info())
2018-08-24 05:59:23.100 53672 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oslo_utils/excutils.py", line 220, in __exit__
2018-08-24 05:59:23.100 53672 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher     self.force_reraise()
2018-08-24 05:59:23.100 53672 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oslo_utils/excutils.py", line 196, in force_reraise
2018-08-24 05:59:23.100 53672 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher     six.reraise(self.type_, self.value, self.tb)
2018-08-24 05:59:23.100 53672 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/compute/manager.py", line 375, in decorated_function
2018-08-24 05:59:23.100 53672 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher     return function(self, context, *args, **kwargs)
2018-08-24 05:59:23.100 53672 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/compute/manager.py", line 435, in decorated_function
2018-08-24 05:59:23.100 53672 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher     instance=instance)
2018-08-24 05:59:23.100 53672 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oslo_utils/excutils.py", line 220, in __exit__
2018-08-24 05:59:23.100 53672 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher     self.force_reraise()
2018-08-24 05:59:23.100 53672 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oslo_utils/excutils.py", line 196, in force_reraise
2018-08-24 05:59:23.100 53672 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher     six.reraise(self.type_, self.value, self.tb)
2018-08-24 05:59:23.100 53672 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/compute/manager.py", line 425, in decorated_function
2018-08-24 05:59:23.100 53672 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher     *args, **kwargs)
2018-08-24 05:59:23.100 53672 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/compute/manager.py", line 3158, in snapshot_instance
2018-08-24 05:59:23.100 53672 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher     task_states.IMAGE_SNAPSHOT)
2018-08-24 05:59:23.100 53672 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/compute/manager.py", line 3188, in _snapshot_instance
2018-08-24 05:59:23.100 53672 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher     update_task_state)
2018-08-24 05:59:23.100 53672 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/virt/libvirt/driver.py", line 1747, in snapshot
2018-08-24 05:59:23.100 53672 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher     state, instance)
2018-08-24 05:59:23.100 53672 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/virt/libvirt/driver.py", line 1792, in _snapshot_domain
2018-08-24 05:59:23.100 53672 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher     self._attach_sriov_ports(context, instance, guest)
2018-08-24 05:59:23.100 53672 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/virt/libvirt/driver.py", line 3425, in _attach_sriov_ports
2018-08-24 05:59:23.100 53672 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher     guest.attach_device(cfg)
2018-08-24 05:59:23.100 53672 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/virt/libvirt/guest.py", line 250, in attach_device
2018-08-24 05:59:23.100 53672 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher     self._domain.attachDeviceFlags(conf.to_xml(), flags=flags)
2018-08-24 05:59:23.100 53672 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/eventlet/tpool.py", line 186, in doit
2018-08-24 05:59:23.100 53672 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher     result = proxy_call(self._autowrap, f, *args, **kwargs)
2018-08-24 05:59:23.100 53672 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/eventlet/tpool.py", line 144, in proxy_call
2018-08-24 05:59:23.100 53672 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher     rv = execute(f, *args, **kwargs)
2018-08-24 05:59:23.100 53672 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/eventlet/tpool.py", line 125, in execute
2018-08-24 05:59:23.100 53672 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher     six.reraise(c, e, tb)
2018-08-24 05:59:23.100 53672 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/eventlet/tpool.py", line 83, in tworker
2018-08-24 05:59:23.100 53672 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher     rv = meth(*args, **kwargs)
2018-08-24 05:59:23.100 53672 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/libvirt.py", line 528, in attachDeviceFlags
2018-08-24 05:59:23.100 53672 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher     if ret == -1: raise libvirtError ('virDomainAttachDeviceFlags() failed', dom=self)
2018-08-24 05:59:23.100 53672 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher libvirtError: internal error: unable to execute QEMU command 'device_add': Device initialization failed
2018-08-24 05:59:23.100 53672 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.dispatcher
2018-08-24 05:59:23.292 53672 INFO nova.compute.resource_tracker [req-75c74bc3-26d1-409e-84cd-f1a5730fc70a - - - - -] Total usable vcpus: 72, total allocated vcpus: 44
2018-08-24 05:59:23.292 53672 INFO nova.compute.resource_tracker [req-75c74bc3-26d1-409e-84cd-f1a5730fc70a - - - - -] Final resource view: name=node-2.domain.tld phys_ram=257584MB used_ram=135680MB phys_disk=1618GB used_disk=880GB total_vcpus=72 used_vcpus=44 pci_stats=[PciDevicePool(count=53,numa_node=0,product_id='1515',tags={dev_type='type-VF',physical_network='physnet6'},vendor_id='8086'), PciDevicePool(count=53,numa_node=0,product_id='1515',tags={dev_type='type-VF',physical_network='physnet7'},vendor_id='8086'), PciDevicePool(count=59,numa_node=0,product_id='1515',tags={dev_type='type-VF',physical_network='physnet8'},vendor_id='8086')]
```

Please help us to find appropriate logs to find the root cause

Comment: Try looking in libvirt logs. `/var/log/libvirt/libvirtd.log`

Comment: I dont find libvirtd.log in /var/log/libvirt/ path in the controller.
There is one in different path
 /var/log/upstart/libvirtd.log
Is this one is appropriate log?

Comment: probably, it depends on your OS